# How do you set ngModel of wrapper to refer to value of checked radiobutton inside? AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I'd like to store the value of my radio buttons in a variable.
I tried to do this(but it didn't work):

```
<div ng-model="ctrl.radio" ng-change="doSomething()">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="1" ng-value="1"><label for="1">1</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="2" ng-value="2"><label for="2">2</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="3" ng-value="3"><label for="3">3</label>
</div>
```

By didn't work, i mean that the ng-change event never triggers, which makes me assume AngularJS doesn't magically bind ng-values to a parent model.

I got it to work by putting ng-model and ng-value on each one of the `<input>` elements, but i think that looks messy. Is there a way to do what I originally wanted?